# How to insert a table in to group in Corona SDK (.Lua)?

Tags: android, coronasdk

I get error message when i try to insert a table into a group

My table code is containing images

Here is the code i am using for the table

```
local myJoints = {}

for i = 1,5 do
    local link = {}
    for j = 1,17 do
        link[j] = display.newImage( "link.png" )
        link[j].x = 121 + (i*34)
        link[j].y = 55 + (j*17)
        physics.addBody( link[j], { density=2.0, friction=0, bounce=0 } )

        -- Create joints between links
        if (j > 1) then
            prevLink = link[j-1] -- each link is joined with the one above it
        else
            prevLink = wall -- top link is joined to overhanging beam
        end
            myJoints[#myJoints + 1] = physics.newJoint( "pivot", prevLink, link[j], 121 + (i*34), 46 + (j*17) )
    end
end
```

and here is the code for group

```
    GUI:insert(myJoints);
```

i have my background image in the GUI group and it is covering the table.

I don't know if it is actually possible to insert table into a group

Any help please

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert a table into a group using the "insert" method because that method is looking for a display object. Try calling `GUI.myJoints = myJoints`. Also keep in mind that your table just references your display objects, which is different from having them in a group.